# javaFX combobox promttext dont display after selecting something and clearing combobox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

i'm currently having problem with ComboBox prompt text. setPromptText() works fine, the prompt text is changing until i select item from the ComboBox. After that if i do clear the ComboBox items with getItems().clear(), and set new prompt text with setPromtText(), the new prompt text is not displayed however getPromtText reveal it has been changed to proper one. Prompt text reappear only after changing currently set text to a different one. Is there any way to force update on ComboBox prompt text ?

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
ComboBox<String> textCombobox;
@FXML
Button but1;
@FXML
Button but2;

public void addStuff(){

    textCombobox.setPromptText("Stuff Added");
    textCombobox.getItems().add("Something 1");
    textCombobox.getItems().add("Something 2");
}

public void clearStuff(){
    textCombobox.getItems().clear();
    textCombobox.setPromptText("CLEAR");
}
```

Comment: Try setting the `value` to null.

Comment: Setting the value to `null` clears the selection, but does not cause the prompt text to be displayed again. I have yet to find a way to force the prompt text to show after the value has been changed.